# Delete all local Images and videos taken using UIImagePickerController from the app ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, nsfilemanager, file-manager

I am using the UIImagePickerController to take Images and videos for the App.
What i need to ensure is the app takes minimum storage. So as soon as i have taken the image/video i upload it to my server so that i can access it using a url now.

Thus what i need is whenever the app terminates , **i want to clear all the images and videos taken** , so as to ensure less memory is consumed.

**Please note that i do not want to delete the file immediately after uploading.** I know how to delete a file from a directory individually.

Kindly suggest some other approach if I am wrong.

Comment: How to delete it right after uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no guarantee that `applicationWillTerminate` will ever get called may that is the reason you can not do that (**Thus what i need is whenever the app terminates , i want to clear all the images and videos taken , so as to ensure less memory is consumed.**) . so if your need to do anything before app exist then call `applicationDidEnterBackground`

but you can try on trick for that

[Local notification on application termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988245/local-notification-on-application-termination/21714121#21714121)

Update :

[How to save images from Camera to specific folder in iPhone gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681036/how-to-save-images-from-camera-to-specific-folder-in-iphone-gallery)

and

[Delete files in iOS directory using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369616/delete-files-in-ios-directory-using-swift)

[How to delete ALL FILES in a specified directory on the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226600/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-specified-directory-on-the-app)

Comment: Thanks for the help bro but i need to delete all the images and videos taken from the app . Any help with that?

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta honestly . i didn't do that . either wait someone response or ask different  question

Comment: @AnkitKumarGupta and  Shobhakar Tiwari saying me " where u saving these , i must say you storing this into document folder rit? so you have to delete from there .

Comment: by default it goes to the document folder i believe. So how to delete all the images/videos from document folder

Comment: did you find an answer yet?

Comment: I accept the update as the solution. Worked fine. Thanks @NazmulHasan
Kindly upvote if you liked my question.